# problem with seting GET value

Tags: php, get

in my site i want to set default page to open, using this script

```
if (!isset($_GET)) 
{
    $_GET['id'] = "home";
}
```

when i open index.php it must set $_GET['id'] = "home"
 but it doesn't work. can somebody explain why?

Comment: The $_GET array (which you are testing) is always set

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
if (empty($_GET['id'])) 
{
    $_GET['id'] = "home";
}
```

The $_GET variable itself will always be set, which is why your current code isn't working.

Answer (score 2):

That should be:

```
if (!isset($_GET['id']))
```